# GODOT- how to deal with godot source file, custom modules , and how to import projects?

Tags: c++, github, module, native, godot

I am learning GODOT, and I am following this solution below to connect godot to arduino  via bluetooth with a custom module, I managed to compile the Android Export Templates successfully, and when I get to the next step I’m stuck and I don’t want to mess up all the work in the source file because I don’t understand the principle yet, and several questions come to me;

1. does the compilation create a new custom editor and I have to use it for the new functionality of the custom module (GodotBluetooth) to be supported?
2. how to import the project cleanly without the file ( project.godot )
3. how to do the step  ( 1.Add the module in the engine.cfg:   )

Thank you in advance for your help

https://github.com/favarete/GodotBluetooth

I want to understand the principle of custom modules and the instructions of this project in order to be able to interact physically with godot via arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. does the compilation create a new costumed editor and I have to use it for the new functionality of the custum module (GodotBluetooth) to be supported?

You can build the editor, following the instructions for your platform (see [Compiling](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/index.html)).

However, if you have a module you need to build the export templates. Which means getting Godot source, adding the module and following the corresponding build instructions.

To build the export templates for Android you would go to [Compiling for Android](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/compiling_for_android.html), and then go to the [Building the export templates](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/compiling_for_android.html#building-the-export-templates) title and follow the instructions step by step.

You would then have to set the export templates to the ones you built. Usually you would replace build templates you download from Godot servers with yours. See [Exporting projects](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/export/exporting_projects.html).

However, currently Android is an special case. Since Godot 3.2 it went from using modules to using [Android Plugins](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/platform/android/android_plugin.html). For that you would have to follow the instructions in [Custom builds for Android](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/export/android_custom_build.html).

---

> 2. how to import the project cleanly without the file ( project.godot )

> 3. how to do the step ( 1.Add the module in the engine.cfg: )

I have bad news for you. The `engine.cfg` *was* the  project description file, now it is `project.godot`. The instructions are for Godot 2.

So you don't import a `project.godot` at all. You need to get [Godot 2](https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/godotengine/2.1.6/), and make your project in Godot 2. Then it should have a `engine.cfg` which you can open with any text editor (it is basically an ini file) and modify it.

And yes, that also means you need to follow the [build instructions for Godot 2](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/2.1/development/compiling/index.html) which imply getting Godot source, but on the 2.1 branch.

Comment: Thank you very much Theraot for your clear and detailed answer, you have enlightened my way :)  I will do my best I will read all this and I hope I will succeed, I will not forget to inform you for the next events, thank you again